# Can I use React Router 4 to toggle routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm building an app with a modal sidebar, you know the kind that *slides in*.

These sidebars all have unique routes (ex: **appdomain.com/sidebar/1234**).
I want to show these sidebars when a user clicks on any item in a list of sidebar names.

### Here's the problem:

How can I use Link or NavLink to un-render the route when I click the listed name a second time?

Comment: Can you add some code to get more explanation. Thanks

Comment: You can use `switch` to route between different sidebars with unique Id, and you can use the modal overlay to trigger click to remove the sidebar (un-render in your own words). Try it

Comment: You can create a [custom Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link) that renders a Link with the url set to the actual url for the item or to the root/previous url so the current route can be 'un-rendered'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to click to go to a route and then click again to go back in the browser history:

```js
import { NavLink, Route, NavLinkProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<MenuLink className="btn btn-link" role="button" to="/pricing">
  Pricing
</MenuLink>

function MenuLink(props) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={props.to}
      children={({ match }) =>
        match ? (
          <GoBackComp className={props.className}>{props.children}</GoBackComp>
        ) : (
          <NavLink {...props}>{props.children}</NavLink>
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

const GoBack = ({ history, children, className }) => (
  <div role="button" className={className} onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

const GoBackComp = withRouter(GoBack);
```

TypeScript:

```
import { NavLink, Route, NavLinkProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

function MenuLink(props: MenuLinkProps) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={props.to}
      children={({ match }) =>
        match ? (
          <GoBackComp className={props.className}>{props.children}</GoBackComp>
        ) : (
          <NavLink {...props}>{props.children}</NavLink>
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

const GoBack = ({ history, children, className }: GoBackProps) => (
  <div role="button" className={className} onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

interface MenuLinkProps extends NavLinkProps {
  children: any;
  className: string;
  to: string;
}

interface GoBackProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  children: any;
  className: string;
}

const GoBackComp = withRouter(GoBack);
```

> You can use `<Link>` component instead of `<NavLink>`